# NFC communication - Mifare DESFire EV1 - AES - Init Vector

Tags: encryption, aes, nfc, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I'm using a HID Omnikey 5321 reader to communicate with a Mifare DESFire EV1 tag. I want to write 16 bytes in a standard data file. I'm using the WinSCard DLL (C++) to wrap Native DESFire command in ISO 7816 APDU message structure.

I manage to write data in existing file:

```
File Nb         : 00
Offset          : 00 00 00
Length          : 10 00 00 (LSB first)
Data (16 bytes) : 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 12 34 56 78 00 00 00 00
```

I calculate the CRC from the Native command :

```
Native command : 3D (File Nb) (Offset) (Length) (Data)
CRC = 30 D2 07 00
```

Then I encipher with the session key and an IV set to 00 :

```
32 bytes data to encipher : (Data) (CRC) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

APDU sended :

```
90 3D 00 00 27 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 (32 bytes enciphered data) 00
```

But I have problem when I try to write in file I create before.

After AES authentication with Application Master Key, I calculate the two subkey (K1 and K2). I set IV to 0x00...00. Then I create two file :

File 0

```
CMAC calculation :
  (CD 00 03 00 21 30 00 00 80 00...00) XOR (K2)
  encryption with session key and IV
  copy of encryption result into IV

APDU sended : 90 CD 00 00 07 00 03 00 21 30 00 00 00
Creation file 0 OK
```

File 1

```
CMAC calculation :
  (CD 01 03 00 11 F0 05 00 80 00...00) XOR (K2)
  encryption with session key and IV
  copy of encryption result into IV

APDU sended : 90 CD 00 00 07 01 03 00 11 F0 05 00 00
Creation file 1 OK
```

Then I write data in file 0 in using IV for encryption. I get "1E" error.

I manage to read data in an already existing file :

```
CMAC calculation
  (BD 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 80 00...00) XOR (K2)
  encryption with session key and IV = 0x00...00
  copy of encryption result into IV
```

I use IV to decrypt the data I receive and I get good bytes values. So I think the subkey K2 is good.

I don't know where the problem in my write data command. It may be the IV but I don't know why.

Comment: Could you provide a trace of the commands you are actually sending when you receive this error?

Comment: I send the same APDU for writing data that I described above. I just change the IV for data encryption. I used the IV obtained from the file 1 creation. I get "1E" error code for response

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you are doing. Do you send any commands in between authentication and the write command? Or is it the first command after authentication? Also is that file 0 that you are writing the file that you created with file 0 creation command that you show in your question? Or is it a different file this is important to confirm the communication settings setup for that file)?

Comment: After authentication I create file 0, then I create file 1 and then I write into file 0

Comment: does the write command succeed directly after authentication but does fail when you put the createfile command beforehand?

Comment: Yes it does. That's my problem.

Comment: Does anybody have an answer to my problem? I'm still blocked with it.